# In which thread a C program is executed?

Tags: java, c, multithreading

I think this question is not related to programming but it has got me wondering. I am an android developer and we have to use threads (main/UI or background threads for network call etc.) carefully while writing the code.

As in Android there is main thread and the background thread. If we make a network call in the main thread we get Network on Main Thread/ANR exception and I was wondering since a lot of micro controller programs or Operating Systems Kernels are written in C and C does not support threads unless you use the POSIX library then how does C manages to do all the background task and the UI tasks?

Comment: C doesn’t care about it by itself. And as you said one uses threading libraries. But how does the title and the question relate to each other?

Comment: You have a basic misunderstanding of threads - time for some reading.

Comment: @RichardCritten do you have any links or tutorials online that I can have a quick look at?

Comment: C does not have threads, they are a function of the OS. But if you are writing an OS then threads can be implemented in C.

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks, this makes a little sense now

Comment: Yeah - the C runtime has an entry point named 'start' or _start'.  Execution must be supplied to that location.  Typically, the OS process loader creates a thread to supply that execution.

Comment: @WeatherVane, C optionally has threads since C11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, unless you or a library explicitly uses threads, everything happens on the "main" thread. Additionally, by default there is no UI or background tasks in C.